# Qt positionning: no updates from QGeoPositionInfoSource

Tags: android, c++, ios, qt

I'm starting using qt and I'm trying to get GPS coordinates from my ios and android with C++ following the exemple in official documentation.

The source is not null but the positionUpdated slot is never called.
Any tips would be welcomed, thank you.

```
ConnectionDeviceContextForDebug::ConnectionDeviceContextForDebug(StringDebugDisplayer* debugDisplayer):
    _debugDisplayer(debugDisplayer)
{
    QGeoPositionInfoSource *source = QGeoPositionInfoSource::createDefaultSource(this);
    if(source){
        connect(source, SIGNAL(positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)),
                this, SLOT(positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)));
        source->setUpdateInterval(100);
        source->startUpdates();
        _debugDisplayer->setText("source found");
        //source->requestUpdate();
    }

}


void ConnectionDeviceContextForDebug::positionUpdated(const QGeoPositionInfo &info)
{
    _debugDisplayer->setText("position updated");

}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @RossRogers Hello, sorry for the delay, finally we used QML which is much easier and works well.

Comment: Ah.  My problem was Android Activity vs background Service.  I ended up just writing the GPS code directly in java.  Thanks for the update, @elpha01 .